# ''1064'' with my sql how solve this

Tags: joomla3.0

Δομή πίνακα για τον πίνακα `bak_nal4t_assets`

```
CREATE TABLE  `bak_nal4t_assets` (

 `id` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT  'Primary Key',
 `parent_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0' COMMENT
);
```

Η MySQL επέστρεψε το μήνυμα: Τεκμηρίωση

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 10

Answer (score 0):

Remove the COMMENT at the end of the DDL statement.

```
CREATE TABLE  bak_nal4t_assets (
id INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key',  parent_id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but the next false is Εντολή SQL:

-- -- Άδειασμα δεδομένων του πίνακα `bak_nal4t_assets` -- INSERT INTO `bak_nal4t_assets` (`id`, `parent_id`, `lft`, `rgt`, `level`, `name`, `title`, `rules`) VALUES (1, 0, 1, 419, 0, 'root.1', 'Root Asset', '{"core.login.site":{"6":1,"2":1},"core.login.admin":{"6":1},"core.login.offline":{"6":1},"core.admin":{"8":1},"core.manage":{"7":1},"core.create":{"6":1,"3":1},"core.delete":{"6":1},"core.edit":{"6":1,"4":1},"core.edit.state":{"6":1,"5":1},"core.edit.own":{"6":1,"3":1}}'), (2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 'com_admin', 'com_admin', '{}'), (3, 1, 3, 6, 1, 'com_banners', 'com_banners', '{"core.admin":{"7":1},"core.manage":{"6":1},"core.create":[],"core.delete":[],"core.edit":[],"core.edit.state":[]}'), (4, 1, 7, 8, 1, 'com_cache', 'com_cache', '{"core.admin":{"7":1},"core.manage":{"7":1}}'), (5, 1, 9, 10, 1, 'com_checkin', 'com_checkin', '{"core.admin":{"7":1},"core.manage":{"7":1}}'), (6, 1, 11, 12, 1, 'com_config', 'com_config', '{}'), (7, 1, 13, 16, 1, 'com_contact', 'c[...]

Η MySQL επέστρεψε το μήνυμα: Τεκμηρίωση

## 1054 - Unknown column 'lft' in 'field list'